# Dúvidas sobre o modelo y=a/(x+b)?

Tags: r

Help!
Olá pessoal, alguém conhece esse modelo y = a/(ln(x)-b-e)?
Gostaria de qualquer informações sobre ele pra fazer o ajuste no R. A ideia é saber se há alguma restrição entre as variáveis para fazer o ajuste ou se é possível manipular o modelo para fazer ajustes linear.

Obrigado

Comment: A resposta em baixo solucionou o teu problema?

Comment: Para clarificar: O AP editou a pergunta inicial, que era sobre como fazer o ajuste não-linear no R. @Diogo, não é interessante você editar uma pergunta mudando seu sentido, especialmente se já foi respondida. Se você tem uma nova pergunta (sobre programação, pois apenas de matemática não está no escopo do site), crie uma nova postagem.

Comment: ipsulum recebe a dividido pela soma de x mas b

Answer (score 6):

A maneira mais simples é usar uma regressão não-linear por mínimos quadrados (função `nls`). Matematicamente, este é um método iterativo, que procura valores para os parâmetros para reduzir os resíduos abaixo de um valor limite.

Um exemplo de uso é o seguinte:

```
set.seed(0)    
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- jitter(1234/(x + 1), 0.1)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
nl <- nls(y ~ a/(x + b), data = dat, start = c(a = 1000, b = 2))
```

Os resultados podem ser observados com a função `summary`:

```
> summary(nl)
# Formula: y ~ a/(x + b)
# 
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#   a 1132.5404   548.9356   2.063   0.0417 *  
#   b    1.9850     0.2013   9.863  2.4e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 4639 on 98 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.861e-06
```

Nem sempre a estimativa fica tão "boa", mas isso depende dos dados e da função, não do R.

Answer (score -2):

É possível manipular o modelo pra chegar para torná-lo linear, daí é só 
fazer a regressão simples.

```
y = a/(ln(x) -b - e)  

1/y = (ln(x)-b-E)/a
    = ln(x)/a - b/a - e/a
    = c*ln(x)+d + e'
```

Comment: Faço das palavras do @Molx as minhas.